# ActiveRecord Query to identify orphan child records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, query-string, postgresql-9.3

I have Post and User models. Every post belongs to a user. However, during database import, some erroneous user_ids have been entered on some posts. What would be the query to get posts whose user_ids don't refer to any user? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following, which will result in one `SELECT` and one `DELETE` statement (so 2 queries in total)

```
Post.where('`posts`.`user_id` NOT IN (?)', User.pluck(:id)).delete_all
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be TWO selects? One for pluck, and one for the "where" statement?

Comment: Found an interesting caveat to this one- this works only if there exists some non-orphan records.  If they are ALL orphans, ActiveRecord ends up doing a query with the clause `posts.user_id NOT IN (NULL)`, which actually returns nothing even if records exist.  The join recommendation @user2553863 states below has been the most reliable.

Answer (score 18):

As @user2553863 already mentioned, Rails 5 added support for [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins), meaning you can now do this in an efficient manner and without writing any SQL like this:

```
Post.left_outer_joins(:user).where(users: {id: nil}).delete_all
```

This will find any orphaned posts (those without users) and delete them. Here, `user` is the association name and `users` is the name of the joined table. You do not have to fire an additional `SELECT` to query all the user ids, which might break when you have many users.

Answer (score 7):

Sanjay,

all the solutions proposed works fine for small tables, but depending on the size of the tables involved, and the amount of memory and processing power available, for performance reasons, you might want to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN, like this:

```
Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON posts.user_id = user.id")
    .where("user.id IS NULL")
```

In Rails 5, there is [support for LEFT OUTER JOIN in ActiveRecord](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/12071).

Regards

Comment: Thank you. This would take care of the memory problem likely to be caused by array.

Comment: Thanks! Great tip!

Answer (score 7):

**RAILS 6.1+**

You can make use of the 'missing' method to fetch orphaned records. eg

```
Class User
end

Class Post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is when missing method is used

```
Post.where.missing(:user)
```

This will fetch the all Post records which have a user_id but the corresponding user being deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to both of you. My solution was similar to Manuel's

```
all_user_ids = User.all.pluck(:id)
unwanted_posts = Post.where.not(:user_id => all_user_ids)
```

Then I could destroy all unwanted_posts. Of course, the other solution would work as well.

Answer (score 3):

Note: answers below are valid for Rails 5.0

Many of these answers work fine for a few records or on small tables, but don't scale well at all to having a large amount of orphaned records or when dealing with large tables.

For instance, dealing with two larger tables where `ModelOne` has 707,891 orphaned records:

```
irb(main):032:0> ModelOne.count
=> 2,265,216
irb(main):033:0> ModelTwo.count
=> 5,109,186
```

Trying to execute a query with `NOT IN` will fail as it's too large:

```
irb(main):029:0> ModelOne.where.not(model_two_id: ModelTwo.pluck(:id))
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: MySQL server has gone away: SELECT `model_ones`.* FROM `model_ones` WHERE (`model_ones`.`model_two_id` NOT IN (12068663, 12076647, 12076648, 12082392, 12082393, 12082394, <repeat for the other 5 million ModelTwo records>))
```

Additionally, trying to call `.delete_all` on a query that uses `left_outer_joins` doesn't quite work as expected.

This is the SQL rails generates for `ModelOne.left_outer_joins(:model_two).where(model_twos: {id: nil})`:

```
SELECT `model_ones`.* FROM `model_ones`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `model_twos` ON `model_twos`.`id` = `model_ones`.`model_two_id`
WHERE `model_twos`.`id` IS NULL
```

But chaining `.delete_all` to the end (`ModelOne.left_outer_joins(:model_two).where(model_twos: {id: nil}).delete_all`) generates:

```
DELETE FROM `model_ones` WHERE `model_twos`.`id` IS NULL
```

Which will throw an error.

The most performant way I've found to delete orphaned records comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33180775/2052754) and uses SQL `EXISTS` and a nested query to efficiently find and delete orphaned records.

```
ModelOne.where.not(
  ModelTwo.where('model_twos.id = model_ones.model_two_id').exists
)
```

Which generates:

```
SELECT `model_ones`.* FROM `model_ones`
WHERE (
  NOT (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT `model_twos`.* FROM `model_twos` WHERE (model_twos.id = model_ones.model_two_id)
    )
  )
)
```

Using this query to load the 707,891 orphaned records takes just under a minute:

```
irb(main):040:0> Benchmark.measure { ModelOne.where.not(ModelTwo.where('model_twos.id = model_ones.model_two_id').exists).load }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x0000563cfa227580 @label="", @real=59.61208474007435, @cstime=0.0, @cutime=0.0, @stime=0.23068100000000014, @utime=49.025859000000025, @total=49.25654000000002>
```

Chaining `.delete_all` to this query will work as expected and delete all the orphaned records

```
ModelOne.where.not(ModelTwo.where('model_twos.id = model_ones.model_two_id').exists).delete_all
```

generates the SQL:

```
  DELETE FROM `model_ones` WHERE (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT `model_twos`.* FROM `model_twos` WHERE (model_twos.id = model_ones.model_two_id))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this with straight AR, but it is fairly easy to fix with a little Ruby:

```
Post.find_each { |p| p.delete if p.user.nil? }
```

EDIT:  forgot `.all` doesn't return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`