# How to retrieve ActiveRecord records based on the presence of a related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, `ParentProfile` and `RoomParentAssignment`:

```
class ParentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :room_parent_assignments
```

and

```
class RoomParentAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room_parent_profile, class_name: 'ParentProfile', foreign_key: 'parent_profile_id'
```

I would like to retrieve all `ParentProfile` records where there are *no* `room_parent_assignments`. I'm looking for something like the following statement (which needless to say, is invalid):

```
@non_room_parents = ParentProfile.where(!room_parent_assignments.present?)
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting VS Finding Orphans using ActiveRecord helpers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33180042/deleting-vs-finding-orphans-using-activerecord-helpers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

OPTION 1

```
@non_room_parents = ParentProfile.where.not(id: RoomParentAssignment.all.map(&:parent_profile_id))
```

OPTION 2

```
@non_room_parents = ParentProfile.where("id NOT IN (?)", RoomParentAssignment.all.map(&:parent_profile_id))
```

Both of them are equal to get no parent rooms.

Comment: `RoomParentAssignment.map` generates the following error: NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for #<Class:0x007fdc9b4b5468>. Changing it to RoomParentAsssignment.all.map seems to work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The below query should do

```
ParentProfile.joins("left outer join room_parent_assignments on room_parent_assignments.parent_profile_id = parent_profiles.id").where(room_parent_assignments: {parent_profile_id: nil})
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below code:

```
parent_ids = RoomParentAssignment.select(parent_profile_id)

@non_room_parents = ParentProfile.where.not(:id => parent_ids)
```